# Why stop button is not working in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
// generate a random color - random hex value

const randomColor = function () {
  const hex = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
};

let intervalId;
const startChangingColor = function () {
  intervalId = setInterval(changeBg, 3000);
  function changeBg() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
  }
};
const stopChangingColor = function () {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
};

document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', startChangingColor);
document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', stopChangingColor);
```

This code has two buttons: one to start and the other to stop. When I click on the start button, the color starts changing. However, when I click on the stop button, it doesn't work; it should stop the color from changing.

Comment: Can you please create a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that replicates your issue? Currently, your code doesn't produce the issue you're describing. Perhaps you're clicking on start twice before you click stop?

Comment: Your start function should check if a timer is already running (by checking if the ID is not `undefined`) and do nothing if so. And your stop function should then set the timer ID to `undefined`. This will prevent multiple consecutive clicks of the start button starting multiple timers, of which you can only stop the last one.

Comment: Your code appears to be correct. Please double-check the IDs of your HTML buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of how `setInterval` and `clearInterval` works, you are better off just calling a `stop` just before you start to clear out any activate intervals:

```js
const randomColor = function () {
  const hex = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
};

let intervalId;
const startChangingColor = function () {
  stopChangingColor();
  intervalId = setInterval(changeBg, 3000);
  function changeBg() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
  }
};
const stopChangingColor = function () {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
};

document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', startChangingColor);
document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', stopChangingColor);
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

`clearInterval`, as you an see in the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval), does not care what you pass in:

> If the parameter provided does not identify a previously established action, this method does nothing.

If it's a valid interval ID it will cancel it, if it's *anything else* it will be ignored, so there's no need to check if it exists or anything, just clear it with the variable that holds/will hold your ID.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is when you click "start" button, the code doesn't check if there already has background color change effect. if you click many times "start" button, there will create mulitple background color change effect. While you click "stop", it will **ONLY** stop last one.

and in stop interval function, you need reset id to be `undefined`, it can restart again by click "start" button

like this:

```js
// generate a random color - random hex value

const randomColor = function() {
  const hex = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
};

let intervalId;
const startChangingColor = function() {
  // need check if already has background change effect
  if (intervalId !== undefined) {
    return;
  }

  intervalId = setInterval(changeBg, 3000);

  function changeBg() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
  }

};
const stopChangingColor = function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  // reset the id to undefined
  intervalId = undefined;
};

document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', startChangingColor);
document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', stopChangingColor);
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="start">start</button>
  <button id="stop">stop</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could also just call `clearInterval( intervalId )` before calling `setInterval`, as anything that isn't an internval ID is ignored anyway, That way you can _never_ have two timers running and you don't need extra checks.

Answer (score 0):

As described in most of the above answers one of the reason could be that you are creating multiple intervals by consecutively clicking on Start button and then clicking Stop button, which effectively only kills only last created interval.

My other guess is that, Above snippet that you shared is being used in some library component (eg. React component) which re-renders and losses the value of intervalId on subsequent re-renders. If this is the case then try maintaining intervalId in state.